# Can I set a hibernation/sleep warning on my laptop

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate, notifications

Is it possible to set a hibernation/sleep warning on a laptop like a count down or something?
I sometimes bring my laptop to work and access files off it through my work computer. It is sitting at the far end of the desk so out of reach and sometimes I do not see that is about to hibernate\sleep.
My current system is Windows 7 64Bit Ultimate.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific. See question edit

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, natively you are only able to set a notification if the battery level goes to a certain amount. The below picture shows just this.

[image]

Still, recurring to 3rd party software, there are alternatives on the web. The [first google search](https://www.google.pt/search?q=low%20battery%20software&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:pt-PT:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) led me to this software called "[battery alarm](http://batteryalarm.codeplex.com/)" which is claimed to be as described:

> Battery Alarm is a Windows Vista program that will monitor your
>   battery life and alert you when you are getting low on power. All
>   settings are customizable so it will notify you when you want and how
>   often you want to be notifed.

Still, as referred on the website, it is said to also work on Windows 7.
To note, i have **NOT** tested nor used this software.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't want anything to do with a battery notification. I already have one for that.

Comment: by notification you mean sound alert or systray/window alert? if the hibernation/sleep is scheduled to happen, why not just "unschedule" it?

Comment: The notification can mean any of the above. Sure I can unscheduled it no problem but I was wondering if there was an option for me to have the notification so I can decide if I need to use the laptop or just let it go to sleep.

Comment: if you know the EXACT time it takes to hibernate or at least close enough, you can quickly do a `shutdown -s -t (time in seconds)`. this will give you a GUI countdown for shutdown. `shutdown -a` cancels it. not pratical nor probably safe... but native :\

Comment: Haha cheers mate. Maybe I will go for the non-eco friendly option and to never have it to hibernate. I was just curious if there was something out there that would work easily